# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Cart could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webshop

I just updated my webshop and wordpress, and every time i try to see the shop page I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Cart could not be converted to string in /var/www/eden-outcast.com/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1109
```

But I can't seem to locate the problem or the solution for that matter.

In formatting.php on line 1108 - 1113 it says:

```
function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $string, $strip = false ) {
$string = (string) $string;
if ( 0 === strlen( $string ) ) {
    return '';
}
```

Although I it could be a problem with the database.
Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to cast an object to a string. To do that the object must have the __toString method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your active theme / any active plugins , any of it is trying to use `WC_Cart` object as string.

Firstly, you can try deactivating your theme to see if that notice disappear. If that disappear than search your theme source code exactly where `WC_Cart` object is being used.

If not, that do the same for plugins too, try deactivating plugins one by one to spot problematic plugins and search source code.

Comment: Figured out that a plugin is the problem. I have written to the developer to see if there is any solution. :) Thanks.